# Applications/utilities for handling JB2E files in Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, images, image-processing, image-conversion

JB2E is a file format for 1-bit (bi-level) images compressed in the [JBIG2 compression standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG2).

Unfortunately, it seems to have extremely poor support, even though it's been an ISO standard for nearly 20 years, and is occasionally/often used within PDFs.

When in a PDF, most or all readers (on my Linux distribution) support it, but take a very long time decompressing it - perhaps 5 seconds per page if not more on a relatively new 4-core PC with plenty of RAM.

Outside of a PDF, things get worse:

- Many image viewers won't open a .jb2e file
- Imagemagick won't convert a .jb2e file, saying:

  ```
  convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `JB2E' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
  ```
- gimp 2.8 won't open .jb2e files

How should I handle JB2E files, then? Is it because I don't have latest-and-greatest versions of everything (I use Devuan ASCII ~= Debian Stretch)? What utilities and apps can I use which *do* support .jb2e files?

Required features:

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux

Desired features:

- Libre
- Fast
- Available in Debian Stretch

Comment: [jbig2dec](https://jbig2dec.com/) should provide decoding support, and I was able to convert JBIG2 elements of a PDF document to PNG images using [xpdf](https://www.xpdfreader.com/).

Comment: What kind of "handling" do you have in mind? For example, editing, or just converting into other formats?